# minus 20 pixels at top and bottom of div

Tags: html, css

As a bare bones examples I have those 2 really simple divs:

[image]

(the green one is inside the red one)

Now how can I subtract 20 pixels from the bottom and the top of the green div?

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="rows">
    </div>    
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}

#rows {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    /* margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px; */

   /*  padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px; */    

/*     top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;  
    height: auto; */

    background: green;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/2L6c2bLf/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it without adding padding to the parent div or using a calc in the child div.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2L6c2bLf/9/)

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
#rows {
    position: absolute;
    width:50%;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Why does this not work when the position of `#rows` is relative as well?

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top. When using relative positioning, top overrides bottom, so the div will display 20px below the top of the container, and the bottom attribute is ignored. Since height is also undefined the div has a height of zero. With absolute positioning, top and bottom specified at 20px, and no height defined, the child div starts at 20px below the parent top, and ends at 20px above the parent bottom. Top and bottom effectively set the upper and lower bounds for the div.

Answer (score 4):

Add padding to #container

```
padding: 20px 0px;
```

**Edit**:

as suggested by @Adam you should contain also

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to stylesheet if you want to preserve box height

Comment: #container now becomes 340px tall

Comment: @Brino exactly my thought

Comment: pretty obvious isn't it? :) @frewheeler if it is your thought why you copied my answer into yours?

Comment: @Brino - `box-sizing: border-box` is now a pretty much accepted convention. Add this to the top of your stylesheet to make this answer work: `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` This answer should also include mention of it.

Answer (score 2):

This may be the solution:

```
height: calc(100% - 40px);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L6c2bLf/3/)**

Another solution is

```
padding:20px 0px;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

for your container. `box-sizing:border-box;` preserves the height changing of the container.

Comment: This one looks good but I am just wondering is calc a good practice? Because I tried to use calc in some of my cases but it doesn't work all the time.

Comment: @Eason.Luo Calc works in any browser that supports CSS3 spec.  That's all of them, save for old versions of IE. 8 and below, I believe.

Comment: What If I wanted 20 pixels at the top and 15 at the bottom?

Comment: @clankill3r freewheeler's second solution would allow you to do that by changing `padding:20px 0px;` to `padding: 20px 0 15px;`.

Comment: I've found `calc` to be necessary under very seldom conditions. The best solution is the answer is the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
#rows {
  width: 50%;
  height: 260px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2L6c2bLf/5/